# Django: Number the integer fields of the filtered queryset in order (efficiently)

Tags: django

It is possible to assign sequential numbers to the integer fields in the filtered queryset I am looking for by doing the following, but the query is issued every time I `save()`.
How is it possible to save it?

```py
queryset = Model.objects.filter(user=user)
for i, item in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
    item.index = i
    item.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question completely, but if your problem is that it's issuing too many queries (one per `.save()`). Then you can use [bulk_update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)

```py
queryset = Model.objects.filter(user=user)
objs = []
for i, item in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
    item.index = i
    objs.append(item)
Model.objects.bulk_update(objs, ['index'])
```